# Is this way of mocking a service inside a service correct in jasmine with Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I want these variables to mock some services `helpersCountriesServiceMock`  and `helpersJsonMock`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
fdescribe('TenantsService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;

  let service: TenantService;

  const helpersCountriesServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj([
    'getRegionsList', 'getCitiesList', 'getCodeCountriesList',
    'buildData', 'getCountriesNames', 'getDefaultLanguage'
  ]);

  const helpersJsonMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getJSON', 'getJSONDocumentType']);

  const tenantId = 'tenantId';
  let tenantsServiceMock = new TenantServiceMock();
  let helpersService: HelpersService;
  let store: any;
  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: Store, useClass: StoreMock },
        { provide: Location, useValue: locationStub },
        { provide: HelpersService, useClass: HelpersServiceMock},
        { provide: HelperCountriesService, useValue: helpersCountriesServiceMock},
        { provide: TenantsApiService, useClass: TenantServiceMock},
        { provide: JsonHelperService, useValue: helpersJsonMock}
      ]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.inject(TenantService);
    store = injector.inject(Store);
    helpersService = injector.inject(HelpersService);

  });
```

I use it in the `it` test like this:

Note: I am not using `spyOn` in `helpersCountriesServiceMock` or `helpersJsonMock`. The test passes, but I don't know if I am mocking the service right or not.

```
  it('[getRegionsListByCountry()] should call helperCountriesService.getRegionsList() and get an observable', async () => {
    const regions = [
      { "name": "Zipaquirá", "asciiname": "Zipaquira", "admin1_code": "Cundinamarca" }, 
      { "name": "Zipacón", "asciiname": "Zipacon", "admin1_code": "Cundinamarca" }]
    const code = 'code';
    helpersJsonMock.getJSON.and.returnValue(of(regions));
    helpersCountriesServiceMock.getRegionsList.and.returnValue([])
    service.getRegionsListByCountry(tenantId).subscribe(res => {
      expect(res).toEqual([]);
      expect(helpersCountriesServiceMock.getRegionsList).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
    service.getRegionsListByCountry(code)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First add before describe function

```
@Injectable()
class helpersCountriesServiceMock {
getRegionsList(){},
}

@Injectable()
class helpersJsonMock{
getJSON(){},
}
```

and then inside test write a spy on each function call you need for your test :

```
//for the first service 

        spyOn(service.HelperCountriesService, 'getRegionsList').and.returnValue([]);
//for the second call
         spyOn(service.JsonHelperService, 'getJSON').and.returnValue(of(regions));
```

Comment: The code you wrote is correct, but doesn't address the point of my question